# Remove questionmark from URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having problem removing the question marks from my url.

Now the URL looks like this: www.mydomain.com/development/p/?user=me

But I want it to be like this:

Now the URL looks like this: www.mydomain.com/development/p/me

I have this htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} YOURSTRING=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /development/p/$1? [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you enable mod_rewrite in httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

*will only work if you enable mod_rewrite in httpd.conf*
create a .htaccess file in the root directory and put this in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```