# Deleting the ? from links

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

Basically I have most of my links like

```
localhost/?login
localhost/?register
localhost/?admin

I want to make them look like:

localhost/login
localhost/register
localhost/admin
```

etc. But I remember before that I removed the ? from that, I just don't remember how. 
Couldn't really find any help on this via google but it's probably out there.

Also how I can make

```
localhost/?login&something=123
```

look like

```
localhost/login/something=123
localhost/login/something/123
```

etc.

Comment: no help on google for rewriting a url within a .htaccess? are we using the same google?

Comment: Huh? Remove them how?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553135/remove-questionmark-from-url-with-htaccess

Comment: first result in google http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.htaccess` for that:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?$1&$2=$3 [L]
```

The above will make the following conversions for you:

```
localhost/login               => localhost/?login
localhost/login/something     => localhost/?login&something
localhost/login/something/123 => localhost/?login&something=123
```

Comment: Do I need to put anything more than that in .htaccess?

Comment: It depends. You might need to place some conditions in there to prevent valid files being rewritten.

Comment: Well just putting that in the htaccess and trying localhost/login doesn't work for me

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` file that handles the URL parameters somehow?

Comment: Added if(isset($_GET['login'])){ echo 'Works'; } should work right?

Comment: It depends. You might need to tell Apache not to rewrite any file that exists.